# Getting space for + sign in apex while reading value from URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, url, encryption, browser

We have a requirement where we are encrypting Salesforce ID value using Crypto class method. `Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);`

But it generates a key which contains `+` sign and when we read this value in apex we get space for that `+` sign.

We tried `EncodingUtil.urlDecode` and `EncodingUtil.urlEncode`. In that case `+` sign is getting converted into `%2B` and again we get space for that in the apex.

For Ex -
Encoded value in URL:

```
gAbH0FIEK5l2m8wVKTV+p4R5QLay2D9jZ2BgsyQ3mJ1/9puMMIne6y5P6i3ZRidl
```

Encoded value in Apex:

```
gAbH0FIEK5l2m8wVKTV p4R5QLay2D9jZ2BgsyQ3mJ1/9puMMIne6y5P6i3ZRidl
```

Can someone please suggest how to handle the situation?

We can handle spaces by replacing it with `+` sign. But I am not sure if it will throw an error for any specific characters/case.

Comment: We'll need to see some code. You're doing something wrong. Tushar's answer is correct, and I tested and verified that `%2b` does indeed convert back to `+`. You've managed to somehow do it wrong (probably by *not* escaping the +, despite thinking you had).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string in URL encode

```
EncodingUtil.urlEncode('gAbH0FIEK5l2m8wVKTV+p4R5QLay2D9jZ2BgsyQ3mJ1/9puMMIne6y5P6i3ZRidl','UTF-8');
```

Which will replace it to

```
gAbH0FIEK5l2m8wVKTV%2Bp4R5QLay2D9jZ2BgsyQ3mJ1%2F9puMMIne6y5P6i3ZRidl
```

Now in class simple get it from apex using `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('parameter Name');` and use it you will get expected output.

[image]

Comment: Tahnks for your reply. But when we decode the value again using EncodingUtil.urlDecode and get the value through apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('parameter Name');
It returns space instead of + sign.

Comment: Hey Tushar!
Thanks for your quick reply. It worked for me also.
I was getting the error because I was decoding it. If we get parameters directly then it gives the correct value.
Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: @GhanshyamKumar if this solved your problem then you can accept this answer.